# Truncate 1-year payments from long schedule in `\case` statement (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I am trying to build a function to look at incoming records that detail monthly payment amounts and remaining monthly pay periods in order to derive what the total annual payments will be.

This is what I have so far:

```
annualizeMonthlyExpense :: MonthlyPayment -> MonthsLeftToPay -> Double -> Double
annualizeMonthlyExpense a b = \case
  (MonthsLeftToPay > 12) -> (AnnualPayment = 12 * MonthlyPayment)
  (MonthsLeftToPay < 12) -> (AnnualPayment = (12 - MonthsLeftToPay) * MonthlyPayment)
```

I believe that at a conceptual level, I have it correct, but my syntax is definitely off.

In particular, I would like to know how to not just to return the total payment for the rest of the year, but also include it as part of a tuple that has the number of periods used in the annualized calculation.

Comment: I don't think you can use lambda case to match on predicates (although there's guard syntax for this). Probably a good way to start out with this is to just accept all the arguments and then introduce a typed hole, then see what you can do with the arguments to produce a value of the expected type. In other words, change the implementation of `annualizeMonthlyExpense` to `annualizeMonthlyExpense mp ml2p d = _`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `AnnualPayment = 12 * MonthlyPayment`? Haskell has no assignment statement, so this makes no sense. Also, all identifier names must start with a lowercase letter; identifiers starting with an uppercase letter are either types or constructors, and as such it is (usually) impossible to do calculations with them.

Comment: `\case` defines an anonymous function. That's why the extension that you enabled to get it is called *lambda* case.

Comment: Also, as for `\case`, as @SilvioMayolo has already mentioned this requires the `LambdaCase` syntax extension to be enabled. If you haven't done that, you'll have to define an auxiliary variable like `\x -> case x of <stuff>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern matching doesn't work like that: patterns cannot be boolean conditions, they have to be data shapes, e.g. `Just x` or `a:b:c` or `Right y` or `Left Nothing` or some such.

To use boolean conditions like this, use function guards:

```
annualizeMonthlyExpense a b
  | (MonthsLeftToPay > 12) = (AnnualPayment = 12 * MonthlyPayment)
  | otherwise = (AnnualPayment = (12 - MonthsLeftToPay) * MonthlyPayment)
```

---

But this is not the only problem with your function.

For one, variables cannot be `CamelCased`, they have to start with a lower-case character. This means that `MonthsLeftToPay` or `AnnualPayment` are invalid variable names.

From your types, I can guess that by `MonthsLeftToPay` you probably meant the second parameter, which you named `b`. Similarly, `MonthlyPayment` probably means `a`. But I'm not sure what `AnnualPayment` is.

Judging by the non-sensical syntax `AnnualPayment = ...`, I infer that perhaps you meant it to be the result of the function? If so, just write the result after the equality sign:

```
annualizeMonthlyExpense a b
  | b > 12 = 12 * a
  | otherwise = (12 - b) * a
```

---

Further, your type signature specifies three parameters (`MonthlyPayment`, `MonthsLeftToPay`, and `Double`), but your argument list names only two. This will not compile.

If you meant to completely ignore the third parameter, you can use an underscore in its place:

```
annualizeMonthlyExpense a b _
  | b > 12 = 12 * a
  | otherwise = (12 - b) * a
```

Comment: This answer could be slightly enhanced by mentioning `MultiWayIf` and that you _can_ have one or more conditions _after_ a pattern in a `case` expression.

Comment: `MultiWayIf` doesn't really don't anything here compared to guards. It's only useful in the middle of expression.